# Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu creates an url I didn't expect

Tags: html, zend-framework, url

I used a small tutorial to create a menu through the Navigation_Menu view helper. I created my Zend folder inside a subfolder of localhost so now I can access this in my brwoser with

```
localhost/project/public
```

Now the menu  gets a relative url from my config. For instance 'about' maps to `/index/about`. Now my view helper maps 'about' to `localhost/index/about`. How can I map this to `localhost/project/public/index/about` without altering my config file?

Most probably, this is not Zend specific, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: On a sidenote: i strongly recommend you to work with virtual hosts, like "project.loc" as a domain. Whereas the domain maps to "$apacheroot/htdocs/project/public" or something like that ;) It's easy to set up

Comment: jan, taking @sam's advice above will probably solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Xampp/Apache lokal Webserver, here's the HowTo on setting up a local Domain

1. Go to your `$xamppRoot / apache / conf / extra` Folder
2. Inside that open `http-vhosts.conf`
3. In the Top commented area, make sure to uncomment the following line    NameVirtualHost *:80
4. Now comes the variable part and i will just post my Structure. You may edit `Servername` (which basically is the url/domain), `DocumentRoot` (which is the path to project/public), `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV $yourenv` (Zend Config Environment) and `<Directory ...>` (which once again is the path to project/public)

   ```
   <Virtualhost *:80>
     ServerName hod.dev
     DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\prvt\cahod\public"

     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "local"

     <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\prvt\cahod\public>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

With this your Apache now knows how to Set up a local domain. The only thing left to do now is to make your local machine not access the internet when accessing `http://hod.dev`

1. Go to Windows / system32 / drivers / etc
2. Open `HOSTS` (you may use a simple text editor)
3. Inside this you'll see some lines already
4. Just add `127.0.0.1  hod.dev`
5. Save it and have fun with your local domain

PS: I'm sorry that the code-block above does look shitty, but somehow it doesn't work really well in here - breaks the code somehow :(

Comment: I edited some of the info to fit my needs (seeing I work on a mac) but I can't seem to make it work! I'll have another look in a bit. Thanks for the info btw ;)

Comment: Well the apache part should be the same for mac and windows, just that the paths might look different. Where/If a Mac has a hosts File, i really don't know, google might help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set or change the `baseUrl` parameter in your configuration file. Something like the following:

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/project/public"
```

Hope that helps,